# In wireless networks, how do Service Sets and Basic Service Sets relate to each other, if they do?

Tags: wireless, access-point

I am beginning to learn about networks and wireless networks, specifically, and am having trouble grasping how do `Service Sets` and `Basic Service Sets` **relate** to each other, if they do.

Are `Basic Service Sets` sub sets of `Service Sets` ? Can the same `Basic Service Set` (`access point`) be in use by different `Service Sets` ?

Can anyone shed some light ?

Comment: please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_(802.11_network). brief summary: In means of wireless, service sets are a group of devices that shares the same service set identifier(SSID). There are two main types, basic (BSS) and extended (ESS). basic is consists of a  single connection point (one ap, host to host ad-hoc, meshed single ap). Extended consists of several APs (several BSS) that act as a single logical link and gave out same or similar service via shared authentication methods.

Comment: @kayaatabey: thanks for that. I have read the wiki entry on [WLAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_LAN), but not the one you share on Service Set. It does add.

Comment: [one bit more](https://techpracticetests.com/what-is-the-relationship-between-a-basic-service-set-bss-and-ssid_question-answers194968)